# How to put preOrdered AVL tree key numbers into an array in C

Tags: c, unit-testing, binary-search-tree

I'm struggling with AVL tree testing. My program is working as intended, however I cannot figure out how to put the numbers into the correct form.
My testing code:

```
void test_left_rotation_with_parent() {
//Arrange
struct Node* root = NULL;
int insert_nodes[] = { 5,10,15 };
int test_output[6]; // this is where my numbers should be
int correct_output[] = { 10,2,5,1,15,1, };
char* passed = PASSED;

//Act
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    root = add(root, insert_nodes[i]);
}


preOrder(root); // this is my function, see below
int index = print_pre_order(root, test_output, 0); // I cannot figure out what this is for

//Assert
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (correct_output[i] != test_output[i]) {
        passed = FAILED;
        break;
    }
}

printf("%s: %s\n", __func__, passed);
```

I have a function named preOrder which looks like this:

```
void preOrder(struct Node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d,", root->key);   
        printf("%d,", root->height);
        preOrder(root->link[0]); // left
        preOrder(root->link[1]); // right
    }
}
```

The output:

```
10,2,5,1,15,1,test_left_rotation_with_parent: FAILED
```

I need to put these numbers exactly in this order to the array, so key goes to the first place, height to the second for every node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global variable that has the index to the array. With every insert (your `printf`) it increments the variable. The array(s) must also be global. `preOrder` can now look like:

```
int test_output[6], index=0;  // is 6 large enough?

void preOrder(struct Node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        test_output[index++]= root->key;
        test_output[index++]= root->height;
        preOrder(root->link[0]); // left
        preOrder(root->link[1]); // right
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. For this specific test the size 6 was big enough, but for the other tests I needed to extend it.